# Need to change the woocommerce variation price prefix

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, prefix, product-variations

We need to add the "AUD" prefix to the product price of a variable product.

We are already adding the AUD to all other pricing output but this one won't stick.

When viewing a product the pricing line reads "AUD $80.30 - $385.00 inc. GST". After selecting your variations the price that comes up just above the qty field and "add to cart" button would read "$132.00 inc. GST". We need it to read "AUD $132.00 inc. GST"

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'AUD': $currency_symbol = 'AUD $'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

However there's one caveat:

`AUD $80.30 - $385.00 inc. GST`  will change to `AUD $80.30 - AUD $385.00 inc. GST`

Comment: Thanks for that Anand. We need to keep the "AUD $80.30 - $385.00 inc. GST" format as is.